# Onclick of a link replace the href wiht new href and then click on the same link using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a condition where on click of a link.
I need to replace the existing href value of that link with new value and then click on the replaced link using Jquery.

ex:I have a link with href `/students/6691/movestudenttonewgroup`

onclick of this link I need prevent the default event and then replace the href with new href

i.e `/students/6691/movestudenttonewgroup/70007`

and then again click on the link and at this time it should not prevent the default behaviour

Could you guide how to do this using jquery

Thanks

Comment: In your onclick function add location.href = '<new url>'.

Comment: The jquery method `.trigger()` can fire an event like a click. But why so complecated?

Answer (score 1):

No need to attempt to click on the link once it's been changed, you can handle the redirect with JavaScript:

```
...on('click', function() {
    var href = this.href;

    // Redirect the page
    window.location.href = href + '/70007';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on James answer,  so i do separate answer ; the location.href solution will only work if the function return false.

```
...on('click', function() {
    var href = this.href;

    // Redirect the page
    window.location.href = href + '/70007';
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks. If i would like to send 70007 as parameter to the link  with put method using jquery how can i do it?

Comment: i'm not sure to see what you want exactly .. are you sure you're not looking for making an ajax call ( with put method ) ?

Comment: using the HTML link I am invoking an action in ruby which is mapped to PUT HTTP method. I would like to pass parameters along with the link so that they can be retrieved in the action

Comment: i don't think any major browser let you navigate in PUT method.  You better make your call using jquery $.ajax method,  then on the "success" return of it, move your user to another page using location.href (if needed) .   [Jquery $.ajax method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).